# Android coustom Listview is not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, models

UserInfo model have three fields name,email,photo but want to show only name on the listview. when user click on listview then get all fields like name,photo email

Also want to set filter in listview

My Listview Adapter class

```
public class UsersAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<UserInfo> {
    ArrayList<UserInfo> users;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserInfo> users) {
        super(context,R.id.tvName, users);
       this.users= users;
       this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }

        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.tvName.setText(users.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public UserInfo getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return users.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    private class Holder {
        TextView tvName;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is getcount method it should be as below.

```
@Override
public int getCount () {
    return users.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter already implements methods getItem(), getCount() and store the ArrayList of displayed items, so

if you use `ArrayAdapter<UserInfo>` you don't need to save

```
private ArrayList<UserInfo> users;
```

because in your instance, your constructor give to super

```
super(context,R.id.tvName, users) //users <-- the List<>
```

So you can remove functions, because they're already implementer by the ArrayAdapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public UserInfo getItem(int position) {
    return users.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

And in your createView() you should use getItem(position) like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, convertView, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.tvName.setText(getItem(position).getName()); //<--------------
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the user apk said, your `getCount()` method need to show how many items there are on your adapter, and also there's no need to use the `[LayoutInflater][1]` as a global variable. On top of that you forgot to initialize the inflater.

So here's what you'll have to do:

1- Fix your getCount() (thanks [apk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4153589/apk) for noticing that)

```
@Override
public int getCount () {
    return users.size();
}
```

2- You can still use the LayoutInflater as global, but there's really no need for that. Anyways, on your getView method, try to do this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context_.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); // Use this to get the inflater.
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.tvName.setText(users.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}
```